# Перевыделение памяти для массива при помощи realloc

Tags: c, динамические-массивы

У меня имеется массив (известной размерности) структур, в которых содержатся массивы (размер которых заранее неизвестен). Инициализирую его я следующим способом:

```
struct neighbor *neighbors = malloc(Nat * sizeof(struct neighbor));
for (int i = 0; i < Nat; i++) {
    neighbors[i].num = 0;
    neighbors[i].arr = (int*)malloc(0 * sizeof(int));
}
```

(переменная num отображает количество элементов в массиве arr)

В дальнейшем мне нужно будет заполнять эти массивы подходящими значениями (если таковые найдутся) и сейчас каждый раз, когда я нахожу новое значение я перевыделяю память таким способом:

```
neighbors[i].num++;
neighbors[i].arr = (int*)realloc(neighbors[i].arr, neighbors[i].num * sizeof(int));
neighbors[i].arr[neighbors[i].num - 1] = j;
```

То есть, каждый раз, когда я нахожу подходящее значение, для занесения его в массив, я увеличиваю размер массива на 1. Честно говоря, я не знаю как в подобных ситуациях лучше поступать, но мне кажется, что мой способ очень плох. С другой стороны, можно каждый раз при заполнении выделять память на несколько элементов (например на 2х текущий размер массива), но в таком случае будет сжираться впустую довольно большое количество памяти. Да и добавится проверка на заполнение массива. Я не знаю насколько трудозатратен realloc и будет ли этот вариант выгоднее, по крайней мере в плане быстродействия.

Собственно, вопрос- как лучше решить данную проблему?
Размер массива neighbors предполагается в районе 300000. А каждый из массивов arr содержит в среднем около 5 значений, но это число может серьезно варьироваться, от 0 и до размера neighbors в худшем случае.

Comment: `насколько трудозатратен realloc` Настолько что десяток-другой проверок подряд на занятость массива будут выполнятся по сравнению с ним - мгновенно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Способ с увеличением размера массива в некое число раз (не обязательно в 2, можно в 1.5 и т.д.) применяется часто, т.к. обеспечивает линейную амортизированную сложность (т.е. общие затраты на проверки и расширение пропорциональны конечному количеству элементов), в отличие от увеличения  размера на 1 или другое конкретное число (сложность квадратичная, при большом количестве расширений неприемлемо).